# Scheme default valued function

Tags: recursion, lisp, scheme, default, tail

I have been struggling for a few days over an idea I had in scheme. I am often writing code in the style of

```
(define fib_h (lambda (n a b) <body ...>))
(define fib (lambda (n) (fib_h n 0 1)))
```

And I thought it would be a nice way to introduce myself into macros. Unfortunately, it seems that it is a little beyond me on how to macro this out. I think I got close at one point with

```
(define-syntax dvf
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((_ f (args ...) (name value) ... body)
      <stuff that didn't work>)))
```

This would define a function "f" that would either take "args ..." or "args ... name ..." and then, if it takes just "args ... " it applies "value ..." to the "name ..." arguments.
I can think of two good ways to do it. The first requires Y combinators, and I really don't want to work with them. The other way would require me to somehow get the number of variables in "name ..." and "args ..." If someone could help me out with this, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably looking for the `case-lambda` syntax, which is described in [SRFI-16](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-16/srfi-16.html). Here's the implementation given there:

```
(define-syntax case-lambda
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((case-lambda)
     (lambda args
       (error "CASE-LAMBDA without any clauses.")))
    ((case-lambda 
      (?a1 ?e1 ...) 
      ?clause1 ...)
     (lambda args
       (let ((l (length args)))
         (case-lambda "CLAUSE" args l 
           (?a1 ?e1 ...)
           ?clause1 ...))))
    ((case-lambda "CLAUSE" ?args ?l 
      ((?a1 ...) ?e1 ...) 
      ?clause1 ...)
     (if (= ?l (length '(?a1 ...)))
         (apply (lambda (?a1 ...) ?e1 ...) ?args)
         (case-lambda "CLAUSE" ?args ?l 
           ?clause1 ...)))
    ((case-lambda "CLAUSE" ?args ?l
      ((?a1 . ?ar) ?e1 ...) 
      ?clause1 ...)
     (case-lambda "IMPROPER" ?args ?l 1 (?a1 . ?ar) (?ar ?e1 ...) 
       ?clause1 ...))
    ((case-lambda "CLAUSE" ?args ?l 
      (?a1 ?e1 ...)
      ?clause1 ...)
     (let ((?a1 ?args))
       ?e1 ...))
    ((case-lambda "CLAUSE" ?args ?l)
     (error "Wrong number of arguments to CASE-LAMBDA."))
    ((case-lambda "IMPROPER" ?args ?l ?k ?al ((?a1 . ?ar) ?e1 ...)
      ?clause1 ...)
     (case-lambda "IMPROPER" ?args ?l (+ ?k 1) ?al (?ar ?e1 ...) 
      ?clause1 ...))
    ((case-lambda "IMPROPER" ?args ?l ?k ?al (?ar ?e1 ...) 
      ?clause1 ...)
     (if (>= ?l ?k)
         (apply (lambda ?al ?e1 ...) ?args)
         (case-lambda "CLAUSE" ?args ?l 
           ?clause1 ...)))))
```

Comment: Just as a small additional remark: `case-lambda` is intended to get standardized within [R7RS](http://trac.sacrideo.us/wg/raw-attachment/wiki/WikiStart/r7rs-draft-7.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

I may be missing the point, but isn't this exactly like the Scheme build-in default arguments work:

```
(define f1
  (lambda (n (a 0) (b 1))
    (printf "n:~a  b:~a  b:~a\n" n a b)))

(f1 10)
(f1 10 0 1)
(f1 10 8 3)
```

yields

```
n:10  b:0  b:1
n:10  b:0  b:1
n:10  b:8  b:3
```

Comment: Standard Scheme doesn't have any syntax for default arguments built in.

Comment: There are no default values in scheme, with default syntax.

Comment: You are right as per RnRS, sorry. But I've actually never used a Scheme implementation that lacked default values.